# What Popes have resigned in the past?

Tags: catholicism, papacy

Pope Benedict XVI recently announced his resignation. What other Popes have abdicated in the past? The media keep pointing to Gregory XII, but it is my understanding that he was deposed by the Council of Constance (involuntarily).

Comment: This question is likely found easily on wikipedia.

Comment: @Narnian see this meta post: http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1488/would-a-question-concerning-politics-or-current-events-within-a-christian-tradit

Comment: @Narnian there is some disagreement on whether Gregory XII was actually deposed or if he voluntarily quit. Wikipedia has contradictory statements on various articles. Having a well-researched answer to this question ["would be a boon to this site."](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1489/1304)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Gregory XII** resigned by proxy at the Council of Constance. He had appointed Cardinal Giovanni Dominici of Ragusa and Carlo Malatesta to represent him, and Malatesta announced the resignation which was accepted by the Council. That Council deposed Antipope John XXIII and excommunicated Antipope Benedict XIII. Gregory's resignation was necessary to end the Western Schism, and was probably at the request of the Council. However, he was not deposed by the Council of Constance.

Martin V was consecrated Pope a month or so after the death of Gregory XII, who lived two years after his abdication. The *sede vacante* period was quite lengthy.

Pope **Celestine V** ruled that a pope had the right to resign the papacy, and he did so after only seven months in office in 1294. In the early church, [Pope **Pontian**](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/12229b.htm) resigned in 235 after being exiled to the salt mines of Sardinia. Other popes who abdicated are **John XVIII** in 1009 and **Benedict IX** in 1045, together with **Benedict XVI** in 2013.

In addition to the above, the [Catholic Encyclopedia](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/01031a.htm) also lists Pope **Gregory VI** who was held to have procured Benedict IX's resignation and was persuaded to resign to avoid accusations of simony.

There are also the doubtful cases of Marcellinus and Liberius; and the non-resignation of Pius VII — he had signed a deed of resignation which would only take effect if he were to be imprisoned in France during his trip there for the coronation of Napoleon in 1804.

Pope Benedict XVI visited the tomb of Pope St Celestine V in 2009, laying his pallium on it and pausing for devotion. He visited again in 2011.

[image: Pope Benedict XVI at the tomb of Pope St Celestine V]

Comment: Good answer, I'd prefer if it used some additional sources to be able to confirm facts, but it looks pretty solid to me.

Comment: This is OT, but is it just pure linguistic irony that a 3rd century salt mine bore the name "Sardinia", or is there actually a connection there?

Comment: I'm also holding out for some more sources, but this is a great answer.

Comment: @DanO'Day Found corroboration for you.

Comment: It is interesting to note that in the terminology used  Pope Benedict XVI  for his resignation, he avoided  using any phrase to his renouncement to the office to the papacy.

Comment: @Ken Actually he did: he used the word *renuntiare,* and renounced the ministry of the Bishop of Rome, Successor of Peter, which is the papacy. [Latin original text](http://w2.vatican.va/content/benedict-xvi/la/speeches/2013/february/documents/hf_ben-xvi_spe_20130211_declaratio.html) | [English translation](http://w2.vatican.va/content/benedict-xvi/en/speeches/2013/february/documents/hf_ben-xvi_spe_20130211_declaratio.html)

Comment: I stand corrected1